# So I want to acces the browsers console to give javascript instructions thourgh a program I will write but I can't google how to

Tags: javascript

Yeah I probabaly don't know the spesific way to google this, I just want to fill a box for example by making a program to type this to console automaticly:

`document.getElementById("Textbox1").value("1234"); enter code here`

I couldn't google it please help

Edit: Maybe this will help me explain? (10 seconds)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foo-iPkAtlo

Comment: You want to print out code to the console? (Your question is very difficult to understand at the moment, a clear in-depth description of the problem would be very helpful)

Comment: So I want to go to a web page and fill a text box(like this comment box) very fast. Like as soon as this page loads I want my code to open the web console and give it a javascript instruction (like the one above). I can manually go to inspect element, go to console and write it myself but I want to make a program to do it so anyone who can do it.

Comment: If this is just for use on your personal browser, there are browser add-ons that allow you to run your own scripts when a page loads (e.g. [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) for Chrome)

Comment: I want to make it a program anyone can use, just an exe.

Comment: JavaScript (generally) doesn't run as an exe. I think you might need to start with some of the basics, you seem to be trying to achieve something without really understanding any of the tech involved.

Comment: When I was an IT technician (many, many years ago), I used a tool called AutoIt that could automate just about any task by simulating keyboard and mouse actions, and the scripts could be compiled into standalone executables. It was Windows-only. Looks like it's [still around](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), though there could be better alternatives available nowadays.

Comment: While not the thing I was looking for I can do everything I wanted this way. Thanks DoctorDestructo

Comment: Correction I could have used this if people still used IE :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function changeInput () {
    const inputText = document.getElementById("from").value;
    document.getElementById("target").value = inputText;
    console.log(inputText)
}
```

```html
<input id="from" />
<button id="btn" onclick="changeInput()">to</button>
<input id="target" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to console log the output, all you need to do is use `console.log`

You can also console.log directly through the console. You could set an interval or timeout to make it "automatic".

If you want to print out code to the console, you can call a function within the console.

```js
var string = "hello";
var ping = string;
console.log(ping);
```

Comment: Why are you passing the string through two variables before it gets to the log? `var ping = string;` seems unnecessary.

Comment: Either way it doesn't matter, I'm just trying to represent an example, I'm not coding out a project.

Comment: Hi I am the op, I want to basically copy and paste a javascript instruction to web console, the one you can open thourgh inspect element.

Comment: Do you want the instruction to be a string or no?